# Compile with a static ross-unrelated library

Tags: ros, rosmake, libraries

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to use a math libary that performs some calculatios, lib.a for example, in a ros package. I use the include statement in myNode.cpp but how do I link it to the executasble? Where do I have to pu the -lfoo -L. flags?

Thanks very much in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30526/compile-with-a-static-ross-unrelated-library/) by [ffusion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2057/ffusion/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-03-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-03-27**:
Duplicate: http://answers.ros.org/question/30532/how-to-include-a-ros-unrelated-library-with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use target_link_libraries as in any other cmake file.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1